# Need message from ActiveX that runs in a thread

Tags: internet-explorer, com, activex

I have an activex control, that I developed myself. The activex runs in a thread to make sure that IE doesn't freeze when its executing the long task. The long task is pretty much looping through 32K rows. Now while its looping I would like to display a message to the IE user notifying him about the row position. That way the user can see the process. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an property on activex, and check it with javascript.

Comment: I did and I even set the property from the thread, however when I access the property from js, then its always empty.

Comment: Never mind. That actually worked. Not sure why it did not work earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your ActiveX control fire events that you sink, instead of polling.

Here is an [article](http://jeffcode.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-create-activex-control-that.html) I wrote on how to do it.  Sorry for the link, it is a lot of information.  Basically you create an outgoing Dispinterface in your type library and call methods on that that you subscribe to via attachEvent() in JScript.